# Custom Notification Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-notifications, localnotification, android-notification.mediastyle

(sleeping sound). How to implement this type of notification in flutter. Such as leading icon , title , subtitle, trailing with play and pause button and background color? image attached in below link.

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm4hJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

you should use a package. i believe that

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

this local notification package will help you.

Comment: but i want to add background color and play or pause button with this notification.how i can do that???